# CorePlot failed to build in XCode 4.4

Tags: build, core-plot, xcode4.4

I am using CorePlot 0.3, everything was ok until I upgraded XCode to 4.4 (2 days ago), CorePlot failed to build and I got some errors with message:

clang: error: -Z-reserved-lib-stdc++: 'linker' input unused when '-c' is present
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

I have tried to search and it seems there are many people have a same problem, and I also found some suggestions and solution to fix it, I have applied to my CorePlot version but no luck, the issue appear in some classes such as: CPTPlot.m, CPTScatterPlot.m, CPTBarPlot.m, CPTPlotSymbol.m.

I have spending 2 days on this problem but still not able solve it, please help me, thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest coreplot will fix your issues with Xcode 4.4 - https://github.com/djw/core-plot

I have not however got those latest changes to work properly in both Xcode 4.4 and Xcode 4.3 so if you are working in teams, different versions, be careful.

Comment: Latest coreplot didn't help me.

Comment: The official Core Plot repository is on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/).

Comment: It looks like CorePlot has been officially moved to GitHub - https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this issue by switching the selected Compiler in Build Options to "LLVM GCC 4.2". It looks like the Validate Settings operation is what is switching the compiler to "Apple LLVM compiler 4.0".

Comment: Im getting the same issue too.... Yet I can actually program my own chart in my own app and it works.... How odd.