# Core Plot clang error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-plot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CorePlot failed to build in XCode 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772545/coreplot-failed-to-build-in-xcode-4-4)

My app was working fine several weeks ago (not touched it since). However, I have opened up Xcode this morning and tried to run it in the simulator and now I am getting this error:

```
CompileC /Users/benthompson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPT-etaoibdncbnbvletceaiimhgxgkq/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Objects-normal/i386/CPTScatterPlot.o Source/CPTScatterPlot.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/benthompson/Downloads/CorePlot_1.0/Source/framework
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Werror -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wmissing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wformat -Wmissing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wsign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wnewline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=30103 -iquote /Users/benthompson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPT-etaoibdncbnbvletceaiimhgxgkq/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/CorePlot-CocoaTouch-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/benthompson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPT-etaoibdncbnbvletceaiimhgxgkq/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/CorePlot-CocoaTouch-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/benthompson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPT-etaoibdncbnbvletceaiimhgxgkq/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/CorePlot-CocoaTouch-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/benthompson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPT-etaoibdncbnbvletceaiimhgxgkq/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/CorePlot-CocoaTouch-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/benthompson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPT-etaoibdncbnbvletceaiimhgxgkq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/benthompson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPT-etaoibdncbnbvletceaiimhgxgkq/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/benthompson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPT-etaoibdncbnbvletceaiimhgxgkq/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/benthompson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPT-etaoibdncbnbvletceaiimhgxgkq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -lstdc++ -falign-loops=16 -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/benthompson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPT-etaoibdncbnbvletceaiimhgxgkq/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Objects-normal/i386/CPTScatterPlot.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/benthompson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPT-etaoibdncbnbvletceaiimhgxgkq/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Objects-normal/i386/CPTScatterPlot.dia -c /Users/benthompson/Downloads/CorePlot_1.0/Source/framework/Source/CPTScatterPlot.m -o /Users/benthompson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPT-etaoibdncbnbvletceaiimhgxgkq/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Objects-normal/i386/CPTScatterPlot.o

clang: error: -Z-reserved-lib-stdc++: 'linker' input unused when '-c' is present
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Ive been trawling the forums for an answer but can't find one. Any ideas?

Comment: I have just had exactly the same issue - and I can't find a way around it. Did you manage to resolve this? I'm even considering restoring my mac from an old backup to get my project working again.