# clang: error: -Z-reserved-lib-stdc++: 'linker' input unused when '-c' is present after update to xCode 4.4

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.4

I've just updated xcode to the 4.4 version and the project I am currently working on is complaining with:

```
clang: error: -Z-reserved-lib-stdc++: 'linker' input unused when '-c' is present
```

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Do you have any idea of what should I check for in order to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue has to do with coreplot: [CorePlot failed to build in XCode 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772545/coreplot-failed-to-build-in-xcode-4-4). Just update coreplot and everything will compile smoothly.

Comment: Seems to be happening again in XCode 4.5.1  Is this because there is a new problem that needs to be fixed?

Works ok in XCode 4.3.3