# All of a sudden: Core Plot in iOS: Apple LLVM compiler 4,1 Error

Tags: ios, xcode4, compiler-errors, core-plot, linker-errors

I don't know what happened; All of a sudden I started getting this error. I  tried re-moving and re-adding Core Plot, but it didn't seem to change anything.  Core plot was originally not giving me any errors, but now I'm getting the following:

```
clang: error: -Z-reserved-lib-stdc++: 'linker' input unused when '-c' is present
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I've seen similar questions on stackoverflow but a) they didn't help me and b) This is a newer version of XCode (4.5.1), so maybe that's part of the problem?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: In the meantime I switched to a static library install, which seemed to work. I don't really know the differences/advantages of one over the other, except maybe it's easier to update the dependent project install? (sorry for my noobnesss)
More detail:

```
CompileC /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-cbzeyejhjnktceepdvakngcfqjhy/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Objects-normal/i386/CPTPlot.o Source/CPTPlot.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/username/Developer/appname/CorePlot_1.0/Source/framework
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Werror -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wmissing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wformat -Wmissing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wsign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wnewline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -mios-simulator-version-min=3.1.3 -iquote /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-cbzeyejhjnktceepdvakngcfqjhy/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/CorePlot-CocoaTouch-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-cbzeyejhjnktceepdvakngcfqjhy/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/CorePlot-CocoaTouch-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-cbzeyejhjnktceepdvakngcfqjhy/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/CorePlot-CocoaTouch-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-cbzeyejhjnktceepdvakngcfqjhy/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/CorePlot-CocoaTouch-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-cbzeyejhjnktceepdvakngcfqjhy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-cbzeyejhjnktceepdvakngcfqjhy/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-cbzeyejhjnktceepdvakngcfqjhy/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-cbzeyejhjnktceepdvakngcfqjhy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -lstdc++ -falign-loops=16 -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-cbzeyejhjnktceepdvakngcfqjhy/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Objects-normal/i386/CPTPlot.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-cbzeyejhjnktceepdvakngcfqjhy/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Objects-normal/i386/CPTPlot.dia -c /Users/username/Developer/appname/CorePlot_1.0/Source/framework/Source/CPTPlot.m -o /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-cbzeyejhjnktceepdvakngcfqjhy/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Objects-normal/i386/CPTPlot.o
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850757/clang-error-z-reserved-lib-stdc-linker-input-unused-when-c-is-present

Comment: Not a duplicate.  Solution there did not work.

Comment: Do you really use the latest CorePlot version? It seems you're using version 1.0. The latest version doesn't carry a version number and isn't available as a pre-packaged download. Instead, you need to retrieve it with hg.

Comment: Oh, thanks.

I tried running the hg code but it didn't seem to do anything -- is it supposed to sit for a while and look like it's not doing anything?

Comment: No, it's not supposed to sit and wait. I'm not an `hg` expert but I think the command is `hg clone https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/`. Have you tried this? Or are you using another client?

Comment: I tried downloading and installing mercurial from here http://mercurial.selenic.com/ (no idea if that's right).   It installed something, but not a program as far as I could tell.  I then ran that command in the terminal, looked like it was doing something; it added a folder core-plot, but never put anything in it.  I left it for a while before closing the terminal though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had this problem after upgrading my xcode version. I found that although xcode was installed, it was still installing some libraries in the background while I was getting this error, once those processes finished, the error went away.

Comment: This is not the case for me.  I think it's probably more to do with not actually using the latest core plot version.