# Core-Plot error

Tags: iphone, graph, xcode4.3

I want to use a graph in my iPhone app. I have downloaded the source code Core- Plot for it, but now when I am trying to run it I am getting an error.

```
clang: error: -Z-reserved-lib-stdc++: 'linker' input unused when '-c' is present
```

Can anyone suggest me what this error mean or how to resolve it.

Comment: Please follow the steps of configuring this library in your project. It looks like you forgot or not follow any step properly.

Comment: I got a solution for it here is the link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772545/coreplot-failed-to-build-in-xcode-4-4

Comment: Great. Please mark your answer as accepted so other user can get help from it.

Answer (score 0):

## `iPhone, iPod Touch, and/or iPad Application

Dependent Project Install
Because frameworks cannot be used in Cocoa Touch applications in the same way as on the Mac, the means of including Core Plot within an iPhone application are slightly different.

First, drag the CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj file into your iPhone application's Xcode project. Show the project navigator in the left-hand list and click on your project.

Select your application target from under the "Targets" source list that appears. Click on the "Build Phases" tab and expand the "Target Dependencies" group. Click on the plus button, select the CorePlot-CocoaTouch library, and click Add. This should ensure that the Core Plot library will be built with your application.

Core Plot is built as a static library for iPhone, so you'll need to drag the libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a static library from under the CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj group to the "Link Binaries With Libraries" group within the application target's "Build Phases" group you were just in.

You'll also need to point to the right header location. Under your Build settings, set the Header Search Paths to the relative path from your application to the framework/ subdirectory within the Core Plot source tree. Make sure to make this header search path recursive. You need to add -ObjC to Other Linker Flags as well (as of Xcode 4.2, -all_load does not seem to be needed, but it may be required for older Xcode versions).

Core Plot is based on Core Animation, so if you haven't already, add the QuartzCore framework to your application project.

Finally, you should be able to import all of the Core Plot classes and data types by inserting the following line in the appropriate source files within your project:

## import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"`

Source: [core plot wiki on google](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications)

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for it here is the link.

[CorePlot failed to build in XCode 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772545/coreplot-failed-to-build-in-xcode-4-4)

Basically the issue was related to Xcode.