# Linker error in project that uses CorePlot, having just upgraded to IOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, linker, ios6, core-plot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CorePlot failed to build in XCode 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772545/coreplot-failed-to-build-in-xcode-4-4)

I have the following linker error  :-

> clang: error: -Z-reserved-lib-stdc++: 'linker' input unused when '-c' is present
>   Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

I've just upgraded to IOS 6  and my project is using the CorePlot library.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the new version of core plot from [coreplot github](https://github.com/djw/core-plot)? Should fix the issue.

Comment: @Jago Bidmead, If this helped, can you please accept it? There is a check mark next to the answer.