# Coreplot Xcode 4.5 Linker Error

Tags: core-plot, linker-errors, xcode4.5

Can anyone help? I've searched high and wide for a solution on this one...

I have recently upgraded Xcode from 4.2 to 4.5, downloaded the latest Coreplot (1.0) and attempted to do the dependent project install and tried the static library using the Coreplot wiki notes but get the following linker error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Werror -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wmissing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wformat -Wmissing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wsign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wnewline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -iquote /Users/carl_evs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Money_Monthly-eyszohglwcbclrfhrqobwkdwqdzo/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/CorePlot-CocoaTouch-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/carl_evs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Money_Monthly-eyszohglwcbclrfhrqobwkdwqdzo/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/CorePlot-CocoaTouch-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/carl_evs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Money_Monthly-eyszohglwcbclrfhrqobwkdwqdzo/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/CorePlot-CocoaTouch-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/carl_evs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Money_Monthly-eyszohglwcbclrfhrqobwkdwqdzo/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/CorePlot-CocoaTouch-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/carl_evs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Money_Monthly-eyszohglwcbclrfhrqobwkdwqdzo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/carl_evs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Money_Monthly-eyszohglwcbclrfhrqobwkdwqdzo/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/carl_evs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Money_Monthly-eyszohglwcbclrfhrqobwkdwqdzo/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/carl_evs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Money_Monthly-eyszohglwcbclrfhrqobwkdwqdzo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -lstdc++ -falign-loops=16 -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/carl_evs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Money_Monthly-eyszohglwcbclrfhrqobwkdwqdzo/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Objects-normal/i386/CPTPlot.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/carl_evs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Money_Monthly-eyszohglwcbclrfhrqobwkdwqdzo/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Objects-normal/i386/CPTPlot.dia -c /Users/carl_evs/Documents/CorePlot_1.0/Source/framework/Source/CPTPlot.m -o /Users/carl_evs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Money_Monthly-eyszohglwcbclrfhrqobwkdwqdzo/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Objects-normal/i386/CPTPlot.o
```

clang: error: -Z-reserved-lib-stdc++: 'linker' input unused when '-c' is present
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Comment: possible duplicate of [CorePlot failed to build in XCode 4.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772545/coreplot-failed-to-build-in-xcode-4-4)